# How to pass a dynamic value to getStaticPaths

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have problem with sending a dynamic value to getStaticPaths. I want to change the url based on my context. But, is this possible i don't know. If not how can I reorganize my code. Here is the thing that I want to do which I point out below as 'query'. I know I can not use my context values within the getStaticPaths. So, how can I handle it?

```
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {

    const url = `https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=[Mykey]=${query}`
    const movies = await axios.get(url)
    const data = movies.data.Search
    const paths = data.map(movie => {
        return {
            params: {id: movie.imdbID}
        }
    })
    return{
        paths,
        fallback:false
    }
}
```

Comment: "I want to change the url based on my context" - could you elaborate on this? What do you mean by "context" in this case?

Comment: A dynamic data coming from my context which is a movie name that written by user.

Comment: [`getStaticPaths`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticpaths-static-generation) runs at build time to determine the paths to be rendered - it doesn't have access to data sent on each request by the user.

Comment: Ok, I wanna elaborate. Firstly, I have a textbox in index page I enter movie name and the page render movies after returning api data which means page changes basen on user's input. So, If I click one of them, the detail page should know which movie I clicked. My problem is I could not fetch the movies id that user entered. Id page do want to know which ids I will return that is why I need to know the movie name in getStaticPaths and request api basen on this name.